# Why does the family choose to travel barefoot?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In *A Quiet Place (2018)*, there is a chance of hurting themselves by stepping on sharp objects, which could make them shout in pain and alert the aliens.

[image]

Why did they choose to travel barefoot?

Answer (score 6):

Walking barefoot is quieter than walking with most shoes.  Hard soles and rubber soles both make noise (felt soles are quieter but hard to find).  Additionally, bare feet allow a person to "feel" their way around more quietly in a way that even socks would disrupt.

That's also the reason for the sand in the picture above.  Walking on bare leaves makes noise; walking on sand, even with a few leaves mixed in, is much quieter.

Comment: While all this is true, wrapping cloth around your feet or walking in thick socks would add protection without adding noise. Some common types of indoor shoes should also be silent, e.g. moccasins or closed slippers. But the writers may have decided that the point would go over better by showing people walking barefoot.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Thick socks would protect, but would also lower tactile feedback, also useful when trying to step quietly.  Let's bear in mind here that there are places and people where shoes aren't standard and they get quite used to walking barefoot, or even [running marathons barefoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abebe_Bikila)

Comment: Can confirm.  I used to run around the woods near my family's cottage barefoot when I was a kid.  There were sharp pebbles, leaves and twigs of all varieties.  Not to mention some of the larger rocks got *really hot* in the summer sun.  It didn't take long for my feet to toughen up to the point where it wasn't a problem.  I occasionally got splinters in my hands when handling pieces of wood, but it was never a problem in my feet.  Anything big enough or sharp enough to penetrate my foot also would have penetrated a sock with little difficulty.